# 0 minus 0 gives carryout of 1 in adder-subtractor circuit

Tags: twos-complement, digital-logic

[image: full adder circuit]

In this adder-subtractor design with the "M" input as the flag for subtraction, 0 minus 0 seems to provide the incorrect Cout. Let's assume that we're only using one full adder here (ignore A1/B1, A2/B2, A3/B3) for simplicity, and `M`=`1`, `A0`=`0`, `A1`=`0`:

The full adder will get the inputs of:

`0 (B0) XOR 1 (M)` = `1`

`0 (A0)` = `0`

`1 (M)` = `1`

This results in `1`+`1`=`0`, with `Cout` = `1` - but `Cout` should equal 0 for a full adder:

[image: full adder truth table]

I think inverting the final `Cout` will provide the correct result, but everywhere I look online for this adder-subtractor circuit has no inverter for the final `Cout`. Is this circuit supposed to have an inverter at the final `Cout` to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The carry out equal to 1 is perfectly normal in this case.

When you work with **unsigned logic** the carry out is used as an overflow flag: assuming you're working with 4-bits operands, the operation:

```
a = 1000, b = 1001 (Decimal a = 8, b = 9)

  1000 +
  1001 =
--------
1 0001
```

produces a carry out of `1'b1` because the result of `8+9` cannot be represented on 4 bits.

On the other hand, when working with **signed logic** the carry out signal loses its 'overflow' meaning. Let's make an example:

```
a = 0111, b = 0010 (Decimal a = 7, b = 2)

  0111 +
  0010 =
--------
0 1001
```

In this case the result is `1001`, that is `-7` in two's complement. It's obvious that we had an overflow, since we added two positive numbers and we got a negative one. The carry out, anyway, is equal to `0`. As a last case, if we consider:

```
a = 1111, b = 0001 (Decimal a = -1, b = 1)

  1111 + 
  0001 =
--------
1 0000
```

we see that even though the result is correct `-1+1=0`, the carry out is set.

To conclude, if you work in signed logic and you need to understand whether there was an overflow, you need to check the sign of the two operands against the result's one.

- Both operands positive (MSB = 0) and result negative (MSB = 1): **overflow**
- Both operands negative (MSB = 1) and result positive (MSB = 0): **overflow**
- Any other case: **no overflow**